# Pivoting column Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like this:

```
username     item_name   total_units_per_username    
abc@gma.com   laptop      2
abc@gma.com   watch       2
xyz@gma.com  phone        3
xyz@gma.com  laptop       3
xyz@gma.com  watch        3
```

what I would like is a table that looks like this:

```
total_units_per_username    item_name               frequency
3                        phone, laptop, watch      1
```

Essentially I want to pivot the item_name column, concatenate all the values over the total_units_per_username, and count the frequency of that occurrence. I'm using Snowflake.

Thanks!

Comment: How do your five rows turn into that single row?

Comment: I'm essentially looking for something similar to the LEAD function, but not be limited to the next row that I partition by. Also, since the total_units_per_username grows over time it isn't a long term solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want two aggregations:

```
select numitems, items, count(*) as freq
from (select username,
             string_agg(item_name order by item_name, ', ') as items,
             count(*) as numitems
      from t
      group by username
     ) t
group by numitems, items;
```

EDIT:

You can also do this with `array_agg()`:

```
select numitems, items, count(*) as freq
from (select username,
             array_agg(item_name order by item_name) as items,
             count(*) as numitems
      from t
      group by username
     ) t
group by numitems, items;
```

Comment: That's what I was originally trying to use! but my server doesn't support string_agg.

Comment: @Julia . . . You must be using an old version of Postgres.  `string_agg()` has been supported since 9.0, which was released in 2010.  In any case, you can use `array_agg()` instead.